# How can I start a script in a remote linux machine from my windows machine from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I need to start a script in a remote linux machine from my windows machine using Jenkins. What would be the best way to do this ? I heard and read up a bit on ssh. but wouldn't that involve using a client like putty ? How could I do this from Jenkins ?

Comment: Could you make the remote linux machine as another jenkins slave? (with appropriate label?)..

Comment: That is one option . I did this instead. Used Plink(command line putty) with ssh to log in and remotely execute the script. I then called this from Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

You must be looking for [XShell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin) in Jenkins.

Here is an extract from plugin help section-

> Runs a shell script (defaults to sh, but this is configurable) for
>   building the project. The script will be run with the workspace as the
>   current directory. Type in the contents of your shell script. If your
>   shell script has no header line like #!/bin/sh —, then the shell
>   configured system-wide will be used, but you can also use the header
>   line to write script in another language (like #!/bin/perl) or control
>   the options that shell uses. By default, the shell will be invoked
>   with the "-ex" option. So all of the commands are printed before being
>   executed, and the build is considered a failure if any of the commands
>   exits with a non-zero exit code. Again, add the #!/bin/... line to
>   change this behavior.
>
> As a best practice, try not to put a long shell script in here.
>   Instead, consider adding the shell script in SCM and simply call that
>   shell script from Jenkins (via bash -ex myscript.sh or something like
>   that), so that you can track changes in your shell script.